# XNA C# Destructible Terrain

Tags: c#, xna, 2d, textures, terrain

I am currently working on a game in which players can destruct the terrain. Unfortunately, I am getting this exception after using the `SetData` method on my terrain texture:

> You may not call SetData on a resource while it is actively set on the
>   GraphicsDevice. Unset it from the device before calling SetData.

Now, before anyone says that there are other topics on this problem, I have looked at all of those. They all say to make sure not to call the method within `Draw()`, but I only use it in `Update()` anyways. Here is the code I am currently using to destruct the terrain:

```
public class Terrain
{
    private Texture2D Image;


    public Rectangle Bounds { get; protected set; }

    public Terrain(ContentManager Content)
    {
        Image = Content.Load<Texture2D>("Terrain");
        Bounds = new Rectangle(0, 400, Image.Width, Image.Height);
    }

    public void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
    {

        spriteBatch.Draw(Image, Bounds, Color.White);


    }

    public void Update()
    {
        if (Globals.newState.LeftButton == ButtonState.Pressed)
        {
            Point mousePosition = new Point(Globals.newState.X, Globals.newState.Y);


            if(Bounds.Contains(mousePosition))
            {
                Color[] imageData = new Color[Image.Width * Image.Height];
                Image.GetData(imageData);

                for (int i = 0; i < imageData.Length; i++)
                {
                    if (Vector2.Distance(new Vector2(mousePosition.X, mousePosition.Y), GetPositionOfTextureData(i, imageData)) < 20)
                    {
                        imageData[i] = Color.Transparent;

                    }
                } 
            Image.SetData(imageData);   
            }
        }
    }

    private Vector2 GetPositionOfTextureData(int index, Color[] colorData)
    {
        float x = 0;
        float y = 0;



        x = index % 800;
        y = (index - x) / 800;

        return new Vector2(x + Bounds.X, y + Bounds.Y);
    }
}
```

}

Whenever the mouse clicks on the terrain, I want to change all pixels in the image within a 20 pixel radius to become transparent. All `GetPositionOfTextureData()` does is return a `Vector2` containing the position of a pixel within the texture data.

All help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: And [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8154784/how-to-unset-texture-data-in-xna-4-0) did not help?

Comment: it seems also that your didn't use spriteBatch.begin(); and spriteBatch.end(). This could be a problem too.

Comment: Never mind, thank you very much! I kept thinking that Textures was static.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must unbind your texture from the GraphicsDevice by calling:

```
  graphicsDevice.Textures[0] = null;
```

before trying to write to it by SetData.